# Scrolling process status window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, vertical-scrolling

As part of a Mac application I am working on, the user fills out a screen full of stuff and then presses a 'process' button.  There are edits performed and if everything passes the edit, a couple of minute process is performed which either end ok or not.  I would like to have that process spit out a series of status and processing messages into a separate scrolling window so that if something goes bad, the user can go back through the log and see if anything shows up there.

What would be the best objects and methods for me to review and use for this type of processing?

Added 11/24/2011

As per the first suggestion, I created a second XIB, created a NSWindowController to match and put it all together as some prep work.  When the button in pressed in the app delegate, I have this thing do the following:

```
- (IBAction)runButtonPressed:(id)sender {

RunResultWindow *wc;

wc = [[RunResultWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"RunResultWindow"];

[wc showWindow:self];

}
```

RunResultWindow is the name of the XIB and the NSWindowController class that controls it.  I also added a finish button and wired that up with the intention of having the results of the process fill up the text window and then hang there until the user presses 'done' or 'finish' or whatever I wind up calling the button.

It actually shows the window when I press the button on the main window but when the code for the button finishes, the window vanishes.  Clearly I am leaving out (an important) step.

Once I get the window then I can add the text view etc.... and get that working. What I would like is for the new Window to get focus and then close out when the user presses the 'done' button.

Additionally, I got the window for the window controller from the window method (it returned an address) and tried a couple of window focus methods in the windowDidLoad method of the NSWindowController but no dice.

Thanks again for whatever info I can get on this.

Added 11/25/2011

Duh.  Maybe if I make the class instance an ivar instead of embedding it in the button method it will work and, lo, it did.  Le Oops.

Comment: Consider posting your answer as an answer instead of an edit.

Comment: Love to but the code itself does not space out well in the 'Add Comment' box.  It kept running the copy/pasted code together and removing line breaks otherwise I would have.

Comment: Post as an answer, not comment.

Comment: Ok... I will do that next time... and there WILL be a next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to drop a [NSTextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/) into a window where one can select & scroll the text but not edit the contents.

You can insert text as easily as using the `insertText:` method.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll go chase that down.  I'm fairly new to objective-c and it seems like each thing I want to do just reveals a mountain of stuff I need to learn.  It's always good to at least know that if I plow through that mountain that I will end up at my answer and not just a dead end.

Comment: Got the window working and now onto the NSTextView and insertText.  Trudging up the mountain one step at a time.

Comment: Let me finish with the NXTextView thing first... I expect to have that done within two weeks.  If that works, I will DEFINITELY hit this back and give it an big ok.

Answer (score 0):

So... The `NSTextView` and `insertText` combination worked out somewhat ok but I don't' think it is the final answer. First, my understanding is that `insertText` is really only meant for user input and not background 'system' input to a `NXTextStorage` object. I'm not sure why but that's fine so I'll avoid it. There are other options. I did find the `beginEdit` and `endEdit` methods and it works pretty much about the same way though I have some more work to do on some detail delegate methods.

The part that doesn't work so well is getting the `NSScrollView` in the window to update on demand. I do the `beginEdit` and `endEdit` stuff and am able to update the `NSTextStorage` object properly. I can do this multiple times in the same method (a test button on the window containing the scroll view). I can tell that because print-object in debug shows me what I'm expecting at the right times. However, I'd like to be able to show an updated `NSScrollView` multiple times during the court of the `windowDidLoad` method. The scroll view updates properly when the button push method ends.

Here is some sample code. I do mix `insertText` and the begin/end edit methods in here but it was more of a test thing than any code I would use for real....

```
(IBAction)FinishButtonPush:(id)sender {

    NSString *teststring;
    teststring = [NSString stringWithString: @"show"];
    [RunResultWindowTextView setString:teststring];
    teststring = [NSString stringWithString: @"show show"];
    [RunResultWindowTextView setString:teststring];
    teststring = [NSString stringWithString: @"show show show show"];
    [RunResultWindowTextView setString:teststring];
    [RunResultWindowTextView insertText:@"123"];
    NSTextStorage *tempTextStorage;

    tempTextStorage = [RunResultWindowTextView textStorage];

    [tempTextStorage beginEditing];
    [tempTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(5,13)
                            withString:@"Hello to you!"];
    [tempTextStorage endEditing];

    [tempTextStorage beginEditing];
    [tempTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(10,13)
                            withString:@"second change"];
    [tempTextStorage endEditing];

    [RunResultWindowTextView insertText:@"xxx123"];
    [RunResultWindowTextView insertText:@"xxx123567"];
}
```

Even though the `NSTextStorage` object is updated properly, the scroll view only updates when the method completes. My understanding is that `processEdit` is called automatically during `endEdit`. I added `processEdit` in there just to see and all I got was either abends or no change depending on where I put the command.

This got deleted and I'm not sure why.  If you're going to gong the post, please let me know why you did so.  Can't improve my post unless I have an idea what was wrong with it....

Comment: Perhaps I should consider using a NSTableView instead of NSScrollView and do a reloadData?  Does that even make sense?

Comment: Got it.... [RunResultWindowTextView display]; forces the display to update.  There are a couple of other problems in here which need solved but this seems to be the ticket.  The method was under NSView which is why I had a hard time finding it.